# Automapper Generic Repository DI in ITypeConverter (CustomConverter) - Load an entity from id

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

How could we injects a generic repository in ITypeConverter?

The main idea is, based on an Id property, load the whole entity and return it. To do that, i need the repository injection to load the entity, and we have a lot of entities so that should be a generic repo.

Based on @Jimmy Bogard's anwser gave, everything is regard DI package and it is NOT recommended use the ConstructUsingService(...) funcionallity. So I've tried to register my custom converter as transient in DI .net core

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => 
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<MyProfiles>();
            });    
services.AddTransient(typeof(CustomConverter<>));
```

My custom converter looks like this

```
public class CustomConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<long, T>
        where T : MyEntity
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;

    public CustomConverter(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        _repository= repository;
    }
    
    public T Convert(long source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source != default(long))
            return _repository.Load(source);

        return null;
    }
}
```

and my map looks like this (it is a Profile file registered on AutoMapper Program.cs):

```
CreateMap<City, CityDto>(MemberList.None)
                  .ReverseMap()
                  .MapFrom(e => e.State, dto => dto.StateId) //there is an extension to treat this
                  .ConvertUsing(typeof(EntityConverter<State>)); //State and City are MyEntity
```

And the DI doesn't resolve the IRepository when creating the instance of custom converter.. I get this error:

`Unable to resolve service for type Repository.IRepository'1[Model.Basic.State]' while attempting to activate 'AutoMapper.Extension.CustomConverter'1[Model.Basic.State]`.

Comment: Could it be that you didn't add a registration for `IRepository<T>` to your `ServiceCollection`? I'd expect something like this in your list of registrations: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(SqlRepository<>));`

Comment: @Steven, I did the registration of my generic repository but also needed to create the maps between all my entities and the custom converter. Also, I removed the ".ConvertUsing(...)" code piece on my CreateMap so in that way the DI .net core package can handle with all injections.

Comment: You need to show the registration for your generic repo. Also, what is EntityConverter? Your converter is named CustomConverter.